# How do I iterate over/get static members from the variadic template types in a function with no arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, entity-component-system

I need to write a function for an ECS that takes in a variable number of template parameters (Components) and no arguments and will return a list of entities with those components attached.

The format would look like this:

```
auto list = registry.getEntityGroupWithComponents<TransformComponent, RenderComponent>();
```

Within the function, I need to access a static ID of each Component class to determine which entities to return, something like this:

```
template <class... T>
std::vector<Entity> getEntityGroupWithComponents()
{
     auto componentIDs = { T::s_id };
     //return entities with all componentIDs in list
}
```

I've messed around quite a bit and can't come up with anything that produces this behavior, but I'm fairly sure it's possible since I think I've seen a similar API before. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about what you need, but probably something like

```cpp
template <class... T>
std::vector<Entity> getEntityGroupWithComponents()
{
    return {enitity(T::s_id)...};
}
```

?

Depending on how an entity is constructed from a component id.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, the reason the above doesn't work is because I can't access the variadic parameter like this : "T::s_id"

I know how to do the remainder of the function once I have that list of component IDs, which are just static integers of TransformComponent and RenderComponent

Comment: Excuse me? In your "something like this" you exactly access it.

Comment: Yes, that is just pseudo code. Trying to do that results in a compiler error with the message " error: parameter packs not expanded with '...'"

Comment: Actually the format in your answer clued me into the syntax I needed; I think I've solved the issue by using this line: "std::vector<uint32_t> componentIds = {T::s_id...};" If you don't mind, can you further explain the "..." operator's behavior here? I can't find good information on it.

Comment: @Ben Humphries https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack